# Adding a Textview to a relative layout in Android

Tags: android, textview

So I have researched everywhere but no else seems to have this problem probably because they know how to program, but anyways I'm trying to add a TextView to a Relative Layout in my Android app, but no matter what I do I cannot get the text and the buttons I already have in the layout. 
   Here is my code for the activity:

```
public class EnterApp extends Activity {
int marblesInJar=0;
int targetMarblesInJar=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    targetMarblesInJar= intent.getIntExtra("MESSAGE_marbles",0);

    RelativeLayout marble= new RelativeLayout(this);

    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setText("Your marble jar will be full when it has "+ targetMarblesInJar + " marbles. You have " + marblesInJar + " marbles.");
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    marble.addView(textView);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_app);


    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}
```

here is my code for the xml relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".EnterApp" >

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
 android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
 android:onClick="addMarble"
 android:text="@string/addMarble" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/button2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
 android:onClick="lossMarble"
 android:text="@string/loseMarble" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Umm..you are not adding the relative layout called marble to your activity's view

Answer (score 0):

You already have the `RelativeLayout` so you don't need to do

```
 RelativeLayout marble= new RelativeLayout(this);
```

this creates a new `RelativeLayout`. Just create your `TextView` and add it to this `layout` after you `inflate` it with `setContentView()`

```
public class EnterApp extends Activity {
    int marblesInJar=0;
    int targetMarblesInJar=0;
    RelativeLayout marble;
```

@Override

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...    
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_app);     
  TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setText("Your marble jar will be full when it has "+ targetMarblesInJar +     " marbles. You have " + marblesInJar + " marbles.");
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    marble = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout); // id you gave your root layout
    marble.addView(textView);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please click the checkmark next to the answer if that worked for you

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate() method you have the setContentView() method which sets the activity's view to the layout file defined in it. Right Now the parent view of your activity is the relative layout with id "relativeLayout". You need to add your textview to that relativeLayout for it to show up. The code for that is as follows:

RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

parent.addView(textView);

It should show up now.